# How can Partial Artifact download be configured in TFS2018 Update 2?

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

According to the TFS 2018 [Update 2 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2018-update2#improve-release-times-by-partially-downloading-artifacts), the *partially downloading artifacts* feature was added. This is further backed up on the [uservoice item](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/13396200-only-download-artifacts-required-for-task-executio#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D).

However, I cannot seem to find where to configure this option within the release template editor.

They provide a screenshot:
[image: release notes screenshot of partial artifact download]

However, I don't have anything like that:
[image: on prem tfs 2018 release template editor with different settings]

I am confident I am on the tfs 2018 Update 2 release as this is the version specified in the TFS Admin Console:
[image: tfs admin console version information]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release notes are wrong, check this feedback: [TFS 2018 Update 2 RC - Select artifacts to download not available](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/227427/tfs-2018-update-2-rc-select-artifacts-to-download.html)

> Partial downloading of artifacts feature isn't available in TFS 2018
>   Update2 RC. Since this feature has dependency on couple of other
>   features and those features are not enabled in TFS 2018 Update2, we
>   chose to not to roll it out. Having said that feature showing up in
>   docs is a bug - we will remove that section from docs.

Comment: TFS On Prem - crushing dreams and hopes since 2013

Answer (score 0):

I have validated what you're saying. My best guess is that Microsoft made a mistake. It's already a feature in VSTS, so it looks like the release notes are wrong.